# Place ellipsis on seaborn catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, catplot

I have a [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) that looks like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is highlight differences in the graph with the following rules:

- If A-B > 4, color it green
- If A-B < -1, color it red
- If A-B = <2= and >=0, color it blue

I am looking to produce something akin to the below image:
[image]

I have an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here:

```
# Stack Overflow Example
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, seaborn as sns
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

chars = ascii_lowercase + digits
lst = [''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(2)) for _ in range(100)]

np.random.seed(8)
t = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'Key': [''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(2)) for _ in range(5)]*2,
    'Value': np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=(10,)), 
    'Type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
    }
)

ax = sns.catplot(data=t, x='Value', y='Key', hue='Type', palette="dark").set(title="Stack Overflow Help Me")
plt.show()
```

I believe an ellipsis will need to be plotted around the points of interest, and I have looked into some questions:

- [Creating a Confidence Ellipses in a sccatterplot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126061/creating-a-confidence-ellipses-in-a-sccatterplot-using-matplotlib)
- [plot ellipse in a seaborn scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762633/plot-ellipse-in-a-seaborn-scatter-plot)

But none seem to be doing this with `catplot` in particular, or with customizing their color and with rules.

How can I achieve the desired result with my toy example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create ellipses around the midpoint of A and B, using the distance between A and B, increased by some padding, as width. The height should be a bit smaller than 1.

To get a full outline and transparent inner color, `to_rgba()` can be used. Setting the zorder to a low number puts the ellips behind the scatter points.

`sns.scatterplot` is an axes-level equivalent for `sns.catplot`, and is easier to work with when there is only one subplot.

Making the `Key` column of type `pd.Categorical` gives a fixed relation between y-position and label.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

chars = ascii_lowercase + digits
num = 9
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [''.join(np.random.choice([*chars], 2)) for _ in range(num)] * 2,
                   'Value': np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=2 * num),
                   'Type': np.repeat(['A', 'B'], num)})
df['Key'] = pd.Categorical(df['Key'])  # make the key categorical for a consistent ordering

sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Value', y='Key', hue='Type', palette="dark")
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Key', 'Type'])['Value'].mean().unstack()
for y_pos, y_label in enumerate(df['Key'].cat.categories):
    A = df_grouped.loc[y_label, 'A']
    B = df_grouped.loc[y_label, 'B']
    dif = A - B
    color = 'limegreen' if dif > 4 else 'crimson' if dif < -1 else 'dodgerblue' if 0 <= dif < 2 else None
    if color is not None:
        ell = Ellipse(xy=((A + B) / 2, y_pos), width=abs(dif) + 0.8, height=0.8,
                      fc=to_rgba(color, 0.1), lw=1, ec=color, zorder=0)
        ax.add_patch(ell)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with custom ellipses]

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, and satisfies the question as is @JohanC. Thank you. If I were to instead flip the X and Y axis; i.e., the textual key is on the x-axis and the numeric value on the y-axis, would it just be the `xy` argument in the `Ellipse` object that would need to change? TIA

Comment: You'd need to switch x and y, and also width and height.